# How do I make dynamic text to limit itself to a certain point?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to break the text to fit in a maximum area but the area is dynamic and so is the amount of text. I'm having rough time putting it in words so I think this image will help

[image]

The image shows how I want it to be but since the div's size and the text's length are both dynamic; on some resolutions the text breaks down and pushes the button off the div.
Is there any way I can make the text break right on the last line before it gets to the button?

```
.div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


#Button {
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9sw5jhk6/2/)

Comment: Show us some of your code?

Comment: "on some resolutions the text breaks down and pushes the button of the div" I guess you mean different screen sizes? if that is the case, you could use media queries to set different font-sizes at each break point

Comment: Possible answer at another stack... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44770/what-are-the-best-practices-for-dealing-with-desired-line-breaks-in-responsive-w

Comment: If you could isolate your problem in a jsfiddle, you're more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that perhaps word-wrap might be what you're looking for.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: I've tried word-wrap, I'm afraid it's not the case... I've added some code to explain it better and show what's already tried pretty much, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can make the text break right on the last line before it gets to the button?

You can use combination of `word-wrap: break-word;` and `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.text-wrapper {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please see this example

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Gedhang Goreng Lorem Ipsum Dolor Gedhang Goreng Lorem Ipsum Dolor Gedhang Goreng 
  </div>
  <button>Button</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried a wrapper for the text but the wrapper parent div height is dynamic as the web proportions change with the resolution so it leaves some empty space in some cases